# unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 18 bytes

Tags: migrations

I am doing a migration from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.  Its using a MYSQL database (Server version: 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 (Ubuntu)).  With this one particular node type when I drush cr and then reload the page I am given the following error.

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 18 bytes in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->loadFromDedicatedTables() (line 1288 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->loadFromDedicatedTables(Array, ) (Line: 524)
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->mapFromStorageRecords(Array) (Line: 449)
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->getFromStorage(Array) (Line: 415)
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->doLoadMultiple(Array) (Line: 300)
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple(Array) (Line: 139)
> Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\EntityReferenceFormatterBase->prepareView(Array) (Line: 245)
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay->buildMultiple(Array) (Line: 351)
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->buildComponents(Array, Array, Array, 'full') (Line: 24)
> Drupal\node\NodeViewBuilder->buildComponents(Array, Array, Array, 'full') (Line: 293)
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->buildMultiple(Array) (Line: 250)
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->build(Array)  call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 100)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. Support for this callback implementation is deprecated in 8.8.0 and will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. See [https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725'](https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725%27), 'silenced_deprecation', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 781)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 372)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent{closure}() (Line: 573)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

I can see it's caused by an entity reference field. I am using the Bootstrap 4 theme and I have a template override, which is the following one.

```
{% if content.field_business.0%}
  <div class="dimension col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2 text-break">
    <p>Retailer: {{ content.field_business.0 }}</p>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Looking at the database table with `desc node__field_business` for the particular node and the rest of them I can't see any junk data.

```
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | bundle                   | varchar(128) | NO   | MUL |         |       |
    | deleted                  | tinyint      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
    | entity_id                | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | revision_id              | int unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | langcode                 | varchar(32)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
    | delta                    | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | field_business_target_id | int unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

`select entity_id, field_business_target_id from node__field_business where entity_id="429"` shows the following output.

```
+-----------+--------------------------+
| entity_id | field_business_target_id |
+-----------+--------------------------+
|       429 |                      267 |
+-----------+--------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There also does not seem to be anything in the apache2 error.log too.

```
[Sun Oct 03 00:00:21.635998 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1757] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 03 00:00:21.636036 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1757] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Oct 03 01:19:18.993276 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1757] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Oct 03 10:13:42.699740 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1666] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 03 10:13:42.709982 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1666] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Oct 03 13:23:39.109602 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1666] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Oct 03 19:14:05.151979 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1678] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 03 19:14:05.152317 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1678] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I could troubleshoot this? I am pretty sure its not the theme template to cause the issue, since I renames the template (so its not used), clear the cache and the error is still there when I refresh the page. As far as I can see the data in table in looks OK to me.

Comment: By any change you have logger around that function call ?

Comment: I am going to need to read up on it I think.  This is going to take me some time though, since I am not full time.  I will have a look at doing this on Thursday.  Sounds like I need to enable X-debug or something similar...Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: The notice is show in the first line (*Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 18 bytes in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->loadFromDedicatedTables()*). It doesn't involve any template file, since `SqlContentEntityStorage::loadFromDedicatedTables()` doesn't load any template file. As for troubleshooting the issue, you need to install a debugger. Apart suggesting that, there isn't much we can say. We cannot debug a site to which we don't have access.